# What is making these links open as new windows?

Tags: links

```
        <?php } } ?>  
                <?php else : ?>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="John Smith (General Manager) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t1.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>John Smith</h1><p>General Menager</p></li>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="Marry Anderson (Ass. Manager) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t2.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>Marry Anderson</h1><p>Ass. Manager</p></li>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="Micheal Fisher (Graphicer) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t3.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>Micheal Fisher</h1><p>Graphicer</p></li>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="Alexsandra Smith (Personel Manager) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t4.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>Alexsandra Smith</h1><p>Personel Manager</p></li>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="Matheus Prahk (Code Developer) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t5.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>Matheus Prahk</h1><p>Code Developer</p></li>
                <li><div class="columb-shadow2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/theme/minishadow3.png" alt=""></div><a class="team" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/bigimage.png" title="Philips Garden (Online Support) </br>Lorem ipsum is simply dummy data text printing"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/post/t6.png" alt="" class="home-team-img"></a><h1>Philips Gorden</h1><p>Online Support</p></li>
                <?php endif; endif; ?>
```

Comment: A link to the page/site with this problem would help us troubleshoot this much more effectively for you.

Comment: Looks like a HTML/JavaScript question to me. Please improve your question, explain why it is WordPress specific.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some javascript that targets those links and makes them open as new windows.

Try running the page with javascript disabled and see if they behave the same. You can also try adding target="_self" to the a-tags, although this might be overridden by javascript.